# How to find best index for sql table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a log table and it has millions of records. I want to increase my sql query speeds but I don't know how to generate best index group or index groups. How can I find best index for a sql table?

Currently I am using;

Index: my_test_index

Definition:
Type BTREE

Unique No

Columns A 
 F 
 B 
 D 
 C

Here is my all sql queries on log table;

```
$sql = "select *
from log 
where columnA=1 and (columnB=6 or columnB=4 or columnB=7) and columnC= ... order by columnD desc LIMIT 0,100;

$sql = "select *
from log
where columnA=1 and (columnB=6 or columnB=4) and columnE= ... and ((date(columnD))>=... and (date(columnD))<=...) order by columnD desc";

$sql = "select *
        from log
        where columnA=1 and (columnB=6 or columnB=4 or columnB=7) and columnE= ... order by columnD desc ";

$sql = "select *
from log
where columnA=1 and (columnB=6 or columnB=4) and columnE= ... and ((date(columnD))>=... and (date(columnD))<=...) order by columnD desc";

$sql = "select *
from log
where columnA=1 and (columnB=6 or columnB=4 or columnB=7) and  columnF= ...     order by columnD desc LIMIT 0,100;

$sql = "select *
from log
where  columnA=1 and (columnB=6 or columnB=4 or columnB=7) and columnG= ...   order by columnD desc LIMIT 0,100;
```

Comment: Read this:  http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index I would suggest are

1. colA, colB, colC
2. colA, colE, colB
3. colA, colF, colB
4. colA, colB, colG

Some additional points:

- You need not have index on date as each row will have different value and adding index doesnot matter much.
- As all your queries are having equivalent check, order does not matter much.
- Also, you can remove one or two index if the frequency of the execution is less as there will be some index on (colA, colB) always
- You can remove the index on a column if the cardinality( possible values) is very less. eg is_valid column with possible value 1/0 need not be indexed. If the value matches more than 30% key value, mysql prefers to do table scan.

It would be wrong to say all 4 indexes are needed. But that the most you need. By evaluating the other conditions mentioned above, you can have lesser indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will create all 4 indexes and check query execution times and will remove some of them wrt data. Are 2. and 3. indexes have true order? I mean why its not A,B,E but A,E,B?

Comment: As you already had an index on A,B,C , its good to have one more with some other pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the distribution of data.

In general if a known column value in a where clause does not significantly restrict the number of rows in question, then an index on that column is worthless for this query. Your queries e.g. suggest that an index con colA would be a good choice. But when you only have very few distinct values in colA, then this won't buy you anything.

Indexes for (date) functions ("function-based indexes) are possible in some RDBMSs, but they are are actually quite rare. If you feel the need for more function-based indexes, there may be something wrong in your overall design.

Whether indexes for "or" clauses pay off is difficult to tell upfront. It all depends on what the query-optimizer makes from your query. In general "or" clauses are rare and if you find yourself writing many queries which contain an "or" clause, there may be something wrong in your overall design. If you really need indexes for or-ed columns, then a bitmap-index may help, but they come with their own problems.

Indexes usually don't help with "order by"

In general, design you indexes in a way so they significantly narrow down the search space of your queries. There is no need to narrow it down to the one and only matching row. If you get down to 10% of the total number of rows, then an index will pay off.

Indexes always slow down inserts and updates. It is a reasonable approach to start with no indexes at all, except for the ones you need for primary and unique keys.